# Hit button once to show UIImage. Hit button again to hide UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I researched on this website but couldn't find anything to help me. I'm a beginner in coding so this may seem simple to some of you but hard for me.
I have an instruction button in my game that i press to show a speech bubble giving the user instruction. I am trying to achieve, when I repress the instruction button, the speech bubble should disappear.

.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *instructionsPic;
- (IBAction)instructionAction;
```

.m

```
    - (IBAction)instructionAction {
    instructionsPic.hidden = NO;
    startGameButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

In my viewDidLoad i marked my instruction bubble speech as hidden and when the user hits the instruction button it shows up. So yea, how can i make it disappear again when they click the button again?

Comment: Check the the property `instructionsPic.hidden` to see if it is hidden, if so set it to `YES`. Or simply: `instructionsPic.hidden = ! instructionsPic.hidden`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to toggle the `hidden` property of your 'instructionsPic' each time 'instruction' button is pressed.

You can change your IBAction method to :

```
- (IBAction)instructionAction {
instructionsPic.hidden = !instructionsPic.hidden;
startGameButton.hidden = !startGameButton.hidden;
}
```

I leave it upto you to understand the logic used here.

Comment: Sweet it worked. I wasn't aware of that ! function. Thank you! I will mark as accepted once i can :)

Comment: '!' is  ' logical Not operator'.  It inverts whatever Bool value is given to it. You can read more about it here. http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html.

Comment: @user3763526 Get a book on the "C" language and study it. Objective-C supports all of C and a lot of other languages are built on much of the same operators and syntax.